# Cannot complete ionic start command

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic-cli

I am trying to start a new project with `ionic start myApp blank` and selecting React. After I press enter, I see this output.

```
⠦ Downloading and extracting blank starter (100.00%)
events.js:174
throw er; // Unhandled ‘error’ event
^

Error: TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
at Unpack.warn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/warn-mixin.js:19:40)
at Unpack.warn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/unpack.js:188:18)
at Unpack.Parser.on._ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:82:14)
at Unpack.emit (events.js:194:15)
at Unpack.[emit] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:286:12)
at Unpack.[maybeEnd] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:402:17)
at Unpack.[consumeChunk] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:434:21)
at Unpack.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:365:25)
at Unpack.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:479:14)
at IncomingMessage.onend (_stream_readable.js:651:10)
Emitted ‘error’ event at:
at Unpack.onerror (_stream_readable.js:713:12)
at Unpack.emit (events.js:189:13)
at Unpack.warn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/warn-mixin.js:19:12)
at Unpack.warn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/unpack.js:188:18)
[… lines matching original stack trace …]
at Unpack.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:365:25)
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the @ionic/cli package. This behavior also applied to the Angular option as well and other template options. I am on macOS Catalina, 10.15.3. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Which node and ionic version you are using?

Comment: @sharmag I am using Ionic 5, Ionic CLI 6.1.0, Node 10.15.3, and NPM 6.13.7.

Answer (score 3):

for me, deleting the `~/.ionic/` folder helped,
as there seemed to be some corrupted data, and ionic re-generates that folder for you

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4158) with points to comment [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4158#issuecomment-534498792) try doing following

```sh
npm install -g ionic
```

then run `ionic info`

Answer (score 0):

It works well after deleting the `~/.ionic/`

```
Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.1
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.4.3
NodeJS : v12.16.1
npm    : 6.13.4
```